# behavioral difference between System.in and custom InputStreamReader

Tags: java, polymorphism, inputstream, bufferedreader

I wrote a Java CLI program that reads lines from stdin and outputs a possible completion for each line. I'm attempting to give it a gui, so I'm trying to build a drop-in replacement for `System.in`, to allow users to either use the gui or the cli.

So far, I got this replacement, whose method `add` is called when text is inputted in a JTextArea:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class GuiIn extends InputStream {

    protected LinkedBlockingQueue<Byte> buf;
    protected boolean closed;

    public GuiIn() {
        closed = false;
        buf = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Byte>();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        closed = true;
    }

    /**
     * add strings to read in the InputStream. Arguments are ignored if the
     * stream is closed.
     * 
     * @param s
     *            a string. Ignored if null
     */
    public void add(String s) {
        if (closed || s == null) {
            return;
        }
        byte[] bs = s.getBytes();
        LinkedList<Byte> lbs = new LinkedList<Byte>();
        for (byte b : bs) {
            lbs.add(b);
        }
        buf.addAll(lbs);
    }

    @Override
    public int available() {
        return buf.size();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int read() throws InterruptedIOException {
        if (closed && buf.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        Byte b = 0;

        while (true) {
            try {

                if ((b = buf.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) == null) {
                    if (closed && buf.isEmpty())
                        return -1;
                } else
                    break;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                throw new InterruptedIOException("interrupted: "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

However, when I tried it out with `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));` and attempted to `readLine()` it, it seems to block until it has enough characters (many), despite the fact that the text fed is always appended with a newline by my listener.

On the other hand, if `in` is set to `System.in`, each line is read as soon as it is inputted.

So, my question comes in two parts:

1. Where does this difference come from?
2. How to fix it?

Please note that reading from the bare `GuiIn` byte per byte works correctly, and that I already tried tricks like reducing the size of `BufferedReader`'s buffer.

I also searched the web beforehand: this is not about creating a mock object; and [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) is not an option either: it does not support appending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One source of your problem might be that `InputStreamReader` might insist on reading farther ahead so that it can be sure the `byte`->`char` decoder it uses (and which is opaque to it) has enough bytes to produce a full `char` while `System.in` might know enough about the default encoding to provide just enough bytes.

Before you start doing interactive console stuff with Java you should become familiar with the [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28%29) class and the [readline to Java](http://java-readline.sourceforge.net/) port.

Then, instead of creating `InputStreamReader`s without specifying the encoding, I would abstract at a higher level:

```
interface CommandLineSource {
  String readLine() throws IOException;
}
```

and then you can create one backed by the `FileDescriptor.STDIN`, and another by whatever you like so that you can automate input for testing.

Comment: Good idea to abstract around the problem, though it's a let down in terms of polymorphism. Using console does not seems appropriate since the doc does not guarantee the existence of a console when the streams are redirected (I intend to perform batch processing to analyze many completions). One thing: this is not about testing: I already have JUnit classes interacting directly with the completion classes. Anyway, thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @bernardpaulus, Yeah.  It is a let down.  I know that the default `System.out` does a lot of very OS specific guff to try and function as both a byte and char sink, and I suspect `System.in` is similar.  If you abstract then you could use `Console` where available but when `System.console() == null` you can fall back to a simple wrapper around a buffered reader.

Comment: indeed, it is the decoder that causes the problem: openjdk-6 behaves the same way as the official sdk (java 6) and it's confirmed by a peek into openjdk's source code. Didn't went all the way through the exact decoder class, but that's for another time. Thanks again!